# ITMS-90725: SDK Version Issue with Xcode 13.4.1

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode13.3.1

ITMS-90725: SDK Version Issue - This app was built with the iOS 16.0 SDK. Starting April 2023, all iOS apps submitted to the App Store must be built with the iOS 16.1 SDK or later, included in Xcode 14.1 or later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I update my Xcode to 14.2(latest) and it is resolved the issue for me.